# Unable to make build in ionic

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

```
sudo cordova run android (Used for making android build)
```

But every time I got the following error

Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
/home/user/projectname/myNewProject/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

Tried many things and visited many sites but none of them is working for me.
Please let me know if you know guys
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The exception message has your answer. The message says you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1, which requires Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 but the version installed is 23.0.2. Update the SDK and try again.

To update, follow instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager).

Comment: Could you share the error log ?
Also, what's the reason for not using the IDE ?

Comment: I don't need Android Studio IDE for developing this, so that's why not install the same

Comment: OK. What about the first part of the question ? I need to know why you can't update from the command line to proceed.